# how to map an array of custom type from postgres to java using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, types

I am trying to map an array of custom type returned by a postgres procedure to the java

I have a custom type in postgres as

```
CREATE TYPE public.customtype_sample AS(
    sampleid bigint,
    samplename character varying,
    samplevalue character varying
)
```

The procedure returns an array of `customtype_sample` as column of type `customtype_sample[]` in postgres

I went through various link:
[How to map User Data Type (Composite Type) with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707788/how-to-map-user-data-type-composite-type-with-hibernate)

[Array with UserType in Hibernate and PostgreSQL --> MappingException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219498/array-with-usertype-in-hibernate-and-postgresql-mappingexception)

and may more wrote a class that implements array of sampletype but i end up getting this exception

```
"could not execute query"
```

caused by : `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array.getArrayImpl(long,int,Map) is not yet implemented.`

The error occurs in the nullSafeGet method of the userType

```
@Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names,
            SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        SampleType[] javaArray = null;
        Array array = (Array) rs.getArray(names[0]);
         if (!rs.wasNull()) {
         javaArray = (SampleType[]) array.getArray();//error occurs here 
         }
         return toReferenceType(javaArray);

    }
```

seems when i am trying to get the array of custom type there might be some problem not able to understand how to write usertype class for an array of customtype. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's your JDBC driver version?

Comment: @CraigRinger its Jdbc4

Comment: Er, no. The *PgJDBC* version, like `9.2-1003 JDBC 4`. See http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Comment: @CraigRinger its this 9.1-901.jdbc4

Comment: Couldn't tell you, not my downvote. Try the latest JDBC driver. It's possible you might need to implement the missing method in the driver if it isn't in the 9.3 driver. (You should really show a trimmed stack trace for Java errors, btw, not just the error its self)..

Comment: @craig it was 4 months old question don't know why someone down voted it now . There was nothing bad to be downvoted ya printing an entire stack trace can be only a suggestion.

Comment: It's just one of the fun things you get to deal with on SO - the odd random drive-by downvoter. No point caring.

Comment: Seems to be [this issue](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/63).

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error, and I fixed it by upgrading PostgreSQL JDBC from 9.2-1002-jdbc4 to 9.4-1201-jdbc41

Comment: We're using 9.4 1206 build and still getting the same error.

Comment: I updated to 9.4.1208 and everything seems fine now.