UPSERT native SQL query for Collection as @Param of JPA Repository method
I need to iterate over collection of Enteties and apply UPSERT for each element atomically. As i see it - just need to send this collection into SQL query by SpEL.
I know, what i can iterate over collection by Java code, and send Enteties one by one, but it will not be as atomically as I want to realize. (Or I maybe don't understand some things).
I wrote a query like this
DO
$do$
    BEGIN
        FOR entity IN :#{#entitiesCollection}
            LOOP
                INSERT INTO entity_table AS e (id,
                                               index,
                                               enum_field,
                                               version,
                                               is_active)
                VALUES (nextval('entity_id_seq'),
                        :entity.index,
                        :entity.enum_field.name(),
                        :entity.version,
                        :entity.is_active)
                ON CONFLICT (index) DO UPDATE SET field_value = :entity.field.getValue(),
                                                  version     = :entity.version,
                                                  is_active   = :entity.isActive
                WHERE (e.index = :entity.index)
                  AND ( (e.version < :entity.version)
                    OR ((e.is_active <> :entity.isActive) AND (e.version = :entity.version)) );
            END LOOP;
    END
$do$

for my repository method
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "......")
void upsertCollection(@Param("entitiesCollection") List<Entity> entitiesCollection);

but got an exception
QueryException: Named Parameter Not Bound : entity.version
I understand - the error into SpEL references to @Param, but i can't find the solution.
I would appreciate your help!

this: "(Or YOU maybe don't understand some things)." As long as you run your code in a transaction it will be as atomic as calling that procedure. for your procedure to work you will need to define a type parameter on postgres and then map it on your java code. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/18204780/460557 or the links linked on it.

I have more than one pod of my app. So if them do INSERT query (as part of UPSERT) in the same time (in different transactions), i will get Constraint Exception.  On the other hand i have 500 elements of collection in single message to UPSERT and many messages which i get.

I'm not sure it I understand your statement. If you have more than one "pod" (whatever that is) it makes no difference calling the procedure to do the insert or the code, for each "pod" running a individual transaction will be opened and you will run into the same problem. You can either add exception handling on your application for the constraint exception or you can use the merge command from postgres, see here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74066794/460557
